# Doom 3 BFG edition - cannot spawn characters

Tags: doom, doom-3-bfg-edition, doom-3

I cannot spawn any characters using the console in **Doom 3 BFG edition**. This is what I see when I try `spawn char_hazmat`:

```
] spawn char_hazmat
Writing generated/rendermodels/models/md5/chars/hazmat.bmd5mesh
WARNING: file def/npcs.def. line 1021: Model 'models/md5/chars/hazmat.md5mesh' defaulted
....... Game Map Shutdown .........
...................................
*******************
ERROR: gib model 'models/md5/chars/skeleton.md5mesh' has different 
number of joints than model 'char_hazmat'
*******************

]                         D3BFG 1.1400.346456
```

Then I have to force the game to exit by typing `exit`.

How do I spawn characters?

Comment: Do you get the same errors when trying to spawn other characters, like `spawn char_campbell`?

Comment: @pushasha Yes. Same goes for monsters.

Comment: Is the game from Steam? If so, try verifying the integrity of the game cache.